# Sectional curvature of leaves of foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a $k$- dimensional foliation $F$ of a riemannian $n$-manifold $M$, with the property that the leaves of the foliation have constant sectional curvature $s$, for some $s$, is it true that $M$ will also have the same constant sectional curvature?

Is the same true if sectional curvature is replaced by the Gaussian curvature?

If it's a well known result, any hint at proving this or a possible reference or a counter example otherwise, will be most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: If the leaves have dimension zero, it won't work.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest counterexample is the Riemannian product $$M=F\times N$$
for $F$ a manifold of constant *non-zero* sectional curvature and $N$ an arbitrary Riemannian manifold of dimension $n-k$. ($M$ is foliated by the copies of $F$.)

Any plane that is the product of a line in $F$ with a line in $N$ will be locally isometric to ${\mathbb R}^2$ and thus have sectional curvature equal to zero.

So the sectional curvature is not constant, even if the sectional curvature of $N$ were the same as that of $F$. (Which of course needn‘t be the case anyway.)

Comment: Thanks. Honestly wouldn't have thought of this.

Comment: I‘m really impressed to get so many upvotes for a completely trivial example :-)

Answer (score 8):

The Hopf fibration on $S^3$ with the standard round metric gives a counterexample (one dimensional hence flat leaves).

In dimension 2 (where sectional=Gauss), take for example any non flat metric on the torus foliated by circles.

Comment: Thanks. the first example is a nice one.

Comment: If you liked it, then feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Of course. By the way, is there any result pointing to the fact when my question has a positive answer? Just curious!

Comment: If the leaves are totally geodesic, the sectional curvatures will be the same. If $s\ne 0$, then there are values of $n$ and $k$ for which this is also a necessary condition.

Comment: @daene, the Hopf fibration has totally geodesic leaves, but the leaves are flat and the total space is not.

Comment: @Raziel yes exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 3):

One more counterexample: the hyperbolic $n$-space is foliated by horospheres with common center. Horospheres have zero curvature, the hyperbolic space curvature $-1$.

Comment: Yes, thought of this later on. Thanks for your input.